# kendoDropDownList does not align validation message within bootstrap form-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, telerik

I have an issue where the label containing a validation result feedback message is not aligning when used with a kendoDropDownList (alignment is fine for other forms of input).

The following code replicates the issue in latest Chrome and IE 11. Click "Submit" to view misalignment of "Required" message for the dropdown.

You will see the label does not appear where one would expect it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.office365.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" id="Form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="first">First</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="k-textbox form-control" data-bind="value: first" id="First" name="first" type="text" required validationmessage="Required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="first"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="second">Second</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input class="k-dropdown form-control" data-bind="source: authorisorsDataSource, value: second" data-option-label="Option Label" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="secondText" data-value-field="secondId" id="Second" name="seconds" required validationmessage="Required" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk required"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="second"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Third">Third</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                    <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></i></span>
                        <input class="k-textbox form-control" data-bind="value: third" id="Third" name="third" required type="text" validationmessage="Required">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk required"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="third"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 text-right pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: submit" id="Button">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = [
            { text: "First", value: "1" },
            { text: "Second", value: "2" },
            { text: "Third", value: "3" }
        ];
        $("#Second").kendoDropDownList({
            animation: false,
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataSource: data,
            optionLabel: "Select..."
        });
        $("#Button").kendoButton({
            click: function(e) {
                const validator = $("#Form").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
                e.preventDefault();
                if (validator.validate()) {
                    alert(e.event.target.tagName);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

R.

Comment: you have typo there dude `name="seconds"` to `name="second"` and all works fine here's [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/edUqU)

Comment: ahh, the typo was introduced when creating the sample but the fact it does work in the demo shows I might have a typo somewhere else in my code in the actual page - thanks!